# dart : Why does file.writeAsBytes only receive a portion of a file?

Tags: file, sockets

server side,s.dart :

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> args) async {
  final serverSocket = await ServerSocket.bind('127.0.0.1', 6666);
  print('server');
  serverSocket.listen((socket) {
    final file = File('/tmp/bb/111.deb');
    socket.listen((da) async {
      await file.writeAsBytes(da, mode: FileMode.append, flush: true); //Only a portion of the file is received without any errors.
      // file.writeAsBytesSync(da, mode: FileMode.append);   // ok
    }, onDone: () async {
      await socket.flush();
      await socket.close();
      socket.destroy();
      await serverSocket.close();
    }, onError: (err) {
      print(err.toString());
    });
  });
}
```

client,c.dart :

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> args) async {
  final file = File('/tmp/dart_2.15.1-1_amd64.deb');
  final socket = await Socket.connect('127.0.0.1', 6666);
  print('send file to server:');
  await socket.addStream(file.openRead());
  //await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10));
  await socket.flush();
  await socket.close();
  socket.destroy();
  print('exit');
}
```

dart run s.dart

dart run c.dart

dart_2.15.1-1_amd64.deb 126MB

111.deb 21MB

Can anyone tell me why? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I know why: the callback function is not called serially.
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/48121